# A series convergence problem about Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, improper-integrals, gamma-function, pointwise-convergence

In Apostol Mathematical Analysis Exercise 10.31, the question want us to show that
$$\Gamma(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\dfrac1{n+x}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$$
for $x>0$ where $c_n=(1/n!)\int_1^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^ndt$. This is an easy one. The question after it is asking to show that the complex series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n$$
converges for $z\in \mathbb C$. I find this very difficult for me to prove, maybe I'm missing something.

My approach is using the ratio test
$$\left|\dfrac{c_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{c_nz^n}\right|=\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}|z|<1$$
so we need to show that
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{n+1}\dfrac{\int_1^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^{n+1}dt}{\int_1^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^ndt}$$
so the ratio test will always return $<1$ for every $z\in\mathbb C$.

Notice the integrands in both integrals, I've come up an idea which let $f(t)=t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^n, g(t)=\log t$, then I use the Intermediate value theorem for integrals
$$\int_1^\infty f(t)g(t)dt=g(c)\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$$
for some $c>1$. For this I'm trying first not to consider that this integral is improper, then find out the value of $c$, or some reasonable bound of $c$, but I'm stuck from here. My expectation is that the ratio of integrals is of order $\log n$, but logically speaking it is good enough if the ratio is $o(n)$.

Another idea of mine is to show
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{n!}\int_1^\infty t^{-1}e^{-t}(\log t)^ndt},$$
but this seems even harder.

Comment: Hint: if the series converges for all postive numbers $z$ then it converges for all complex $z$. For positive  $z$ interchange the sum and the integral.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n=\int_1^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ which is an *entire* function of $z$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the solution would be this elegant!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand from @KaviRamaMurthy 's comment. Since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n$ is the real Taylor series for the integral
$$\int_1^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$
and this integral converges for all positive $x$, so the Taylor series also converges for all positive $x$. Now we choose any $z\in\mathbb C$ and realize that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_nz^n|\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n|z|^n,$$
which indicates the complex series is absolutely convergent for all $z$, thereby confirm the complex series converges everywhere.